# How to detect controls in web form ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
Language:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="English">English</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Spanish</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label id="eng_lblContent" runat="server" >english content</asp:Label>
   <asp:Label id="sp_lblContent" runat="server" >spanish content</asp:Label>

</form>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ChangeLanguage();
}
private void ChangeLanguage()
{
        foreach (var item in form1.Controls)
        {
            Control c = (Control)item;
            c.Visible = false;
            if (c.ID.StartsWith("eng")) //error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            {
                c.Visible = true;
            }
        }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
            ChangeLanguage();
}
```

Error:
in this line has error:

> if (c.ID.StartsWith("eng")) // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are the controls created dynamically or why don't you just do eng_lblContent.Visible = True? Furthermore you should read about localization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have so many contorl in web form

Comment: you are just trying to detect `Label` control??

Comment: @Usman , I have many controls with different type

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a trick to do this, since the code show exception because the first control render is `literalControl` that doesn't have id, so you have to pass it using following code

```
if (c is LiteralControl)
    continue;
else
   {
     c.Visible = false;

     if (c.ID.StartsWith("eng")) 
     {
       c.Visible = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You're wrong. Literal control System.Web.UI class control, so it has ID as well.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi is the HTML you have provided is complete??if it is then it is not showing any error on my side

Answer (score -2):

This mean that form1 cannot find control with mentioned id. Try to change to be `foreach (var c Control in Page.Controls)`
P.S. Esko he is right about localization, the way you're doing is not correct.

Here is good example of what I said: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @andrey.shedko should it be `foreach (var c in Page.Controls)` instead of `foreach (var c Control in Page.Controls)`?

Comment: @ekad, yes, this could be this way also, just need call Page object instead of form1.